# Java EE + Wildfly 9: Use directory outside the deployed app for upload

Tags: java, upload, wildfly

I'm developing web application and need to make **upload** of files possible for users. The upload folder is outside of **web application** - in openstack data folder (set in standalone.xml) - example:

```
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <location name="/folder" handler="folder"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                </host>
...

            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
                <file name="folder" path="/absolute/path/on/server" directory-listing="true"/>
            </handlers>
```

If I need to access the files, there is no problem (I just type mydomain.com/folder/xyz.jpg), but **I need to reference the folder from the Java code** (get the path of folder and then upload file in it by user). My Java REST interface serving the upload looks like this:

```
public class DictateUploadResource {

    public static final String UPLOADED_FILE_PARAMETER_NAME = "file";
    private final String UPLOAD_DIR = servletContext.getRealPath("/folder");


    @POST
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {

        String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/folder");
        LOGGER.warn(">>>> sit back - starting file upload..." + path);

        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get(UPLOADED_FILE_PARAMETER_NAME);

        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = inputPart.getHeaders();
            String filename = getFileName(headers);


            try {
                InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);

                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

                LOGGER.info(">>> File '{}' has been read, size: #{} bytes", filename, bytes.length);
                writeFile(bytes, path + "/" + filename);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
            }
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }

    /**
     * Build filename local to the server.
     *
     * @param filename
     * @return
     */
    private String getServerFilename(String path, String filename) {
        return path + "/" + filename;
    }

    private void writeFile(byte[] content, String filename) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info(">>> writing #{} bytes to: {}", content.length, filename);
        File file = new File(filename);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        fop.write(content);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();
        LOGGER.info(">>> writing complete: {}", filename);
    }

    /**
     * Extract filename from HTTP heaeders.
     *
     * @param headers
     * @return
     */
    private String getFileName(MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {
        String[] contentDisposition = headers.getFirst("Content-Disposition").split(";");

        for (String filename : contentDisposition) {
            if ((filename.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {

                String[] name = filename.split("=");

                String finalFileName = sanitizeFilename(name[1]);
                return finalFileName;
            }
        }
        return "unknown";
    }

    private String sanitizeFilename(String s) {
        return s.trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by the "alias is set in standalone.xml"?

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use a system property as the `path` attribute allows expressions. Then in your code just retrieve the property.

Here's a CLI example:

```
/system-property=static.content.dir:add(value="/absolute/path/on/server")
```

Then to change the host:

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/file=folder:write-attribute(name=path, value="${static.content.dir}")
```

You could always use a management client to and read the management resource to get the name if a system property is not acceptable. A system property is easiest though.

Comment: everything's done, still does not work - writes "No such file or directory"... are you sure that you don't have to add some special rights to allow directory to be writable?

Comment: The user running the WildFly process would need read access to show files and write access to write files. That's on the OS side though.

Answer (score 0):

**STEP # 1** : create config file in src folder of web application

[image]

**STEP # 2** : Here is my config file

[image]

**STEP # 3** : Now i choose the event file and get the config properties relative to it and read the connectionURL from the properties file

[image]

```
  InputStream propertiesInputStream = null;
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  propertiesInputStream = EventService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
  properties.load(propertiesInputStream);
  String connUrl = properties.getProperty("connectionUrl");
```

Comment: Calling `getParentFile()` a specific number of times doesn't seem very clean. Shouldn't there be a cleaner solution for that?

Comment: Yea getParentFile() is verbose method see i change it now